# pop_os 21.10 - Disable sleep/suspend when lid is closed & external monitor disconnected

Tags: linux, suspend

New to pop_os, been on different linux distros for couple of decades. I am usually a KDE/Plasma user.

Installed pop_os on an old laptop, where i want to run couple of servers (nessus, docker/minecraft, etc).

Have this laptop connect to a 4 port hdmi-kvm. i want to leave the laptop running when the laptop lid is closed and when i switch monitor to a different computer on the kvm.

However, there seems to be no setting to do it or there seems to no setting to disable the laptop monitor and use only the external monitor.

--> I have installed gnome-tweaks --> does not work
--> I have tried to book the laptop up with lid closed and only external monitor connected - nope, there seems to be no change in settings.

Is this a gnome issue or pop_os issue? Have searched the internet, seems like this is an issue that has been around since 2017 with pop_os and there is no solution.

Let me know if there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Gnome extension Espresso allows you to disable the auto-suspend while docked. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4135/espresso/
It is also able to keep awake while charging if you don't have a dock.